# Why curl SSL disable CURL?

Tags: cpanel

I saw this in cpanel whm on Exhaustive Options List

> CurlSSL [More Info ↑]     This option will make the following changes
>   to your profile prior to the build:
>
> Disables:   Curl

Why?

Which option should I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one enabled. Either Curl (without SSL support) or CurlSSL (Curl with support for SSL).

Do you plan on using Curl with SSL? If so, then you need to install CurlSSL, which will replace 'curl' (without the ssl support).

If you are unsure, I'd recommend going with CurlSSL, as it will work for both http and https traffic.

Answer (score 2):

"curlssl" option will allow for non-ssl functionality as well.

Both still provide "Curl" functionality, CurlSSL just additionally provides SSL support.

Comment: So why should this be disabled? Which option should the OP choose?